# Why does my history.push work in one function but the other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history, react-functional-component

**Problem:**
I have been trying to use props.history.push on my Edit function. I previously used it on my add function and it worked. I have the same imports and the only main difference is that I am also using useEffect in my Edit function while in my add function I only have useState. And also the fact I need to access each id in edit.

**Error:**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

**Attempts:**
I have currently tried using Redirect which just redirected without applying changes. Also using history.push works  within the button onClick but it does not apply my changes. Another solution I have seen often is let history=useHistory() after importing useHistory() but that gives me a hook error which I assumed it may be a version issue. However, my other main concern is that why does it work on my Add() function.

**Add.js click Handler:**

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/add",
    data: body,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  console.log(state);
  props.history.push("/list");
}
```

This works perfectly.

**Edit:**

```
function handleSubmit(e, props) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({
    method: "put",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/update-list/" + testid,
    data: body,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  console.log(state);
  props.history.push('/list');
}

function handleChange(e, field) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setState({
    ...state,
    [field]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

The rest of the code is also almost the same aside from using useEffect so I could give default values to the fields. This has been really confusing me. Any help would be appreciated. And let me know if you needed more details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was passing the props in the handler instead of the Edit function itself, and that is why it did not work. So the code should be:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "put",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/update-list/" + testid,
      data: body,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log(state);
    props.history.push('/list');
  }
```

That fixed my issue and now it works! I'm surprised I did not notice this earlier as it took me ages to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `window.history.push` as opposed to `history.push` to use the function. If the default scope of your function is not `window`, you must manually specify the `window` scope in your function. This problem often occurs when calling functions in an external script file from an inline `script` tag.

Update: Change your `edit` code to

```
function handleSubmit(e, props) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({
    method: "put",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/update-list/" + testid,
    data: body,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  console.log(state);
  history.push('/list');
}

function handleChange(e, field) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setState({
    ...state,
    [field]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately after doing that both of them are starting to give that error and it is still on history. Both the Add function and Edit function are accessible thanks to react router so one working and one not working really confuses me. :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with your information.

Comment: Thank you again but unfortunately it does not work. I also tried doing a windows.history.push('/list') but it told me it is not a function. Do you know if is there any potential reasons to why it might not work in a function and only on a button click?

Comment: Update: I was passing props in the wrong function that is why it kept breaking. Thank you so much for your suggestion either way. Helped me learn new things as well!

Comment: @llamingo You actually could remove the `props` argument within the definition of the `handleSubmit` function.

Comment: No unfortunately that was not the issue in my case and you were still passing props in the handler which was actually the issue. And 'history.push' wouldn't work without the props on its own.

Comment: Oh. I just discarded the problem. I didn't resolve it. We each figured out part.

Comment: Yeah I guess in a way it helped me know that was not the problem which does save time!

Comment: Maybe we need a `feature request`: Allow multiple best answers.